# pyTelegramBotAPI.How to edit/delete message with inline buttons only if message from the same step was already in chat?

Tags: structure, multi-level, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I want my TG bot to have inlinebuttons with categories and subcategories in chat with dynamic change.
But how to send message with subcategories if it doesnt exist and edit message with subcategories if it already exists?
Also, I wish to have a "back" inlinebutton among categories that will delete messages with categories and subcategories and turn to main menu.

Attached my code and illustration of goal.

Help me please!
[image]

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN,
                      parse_mode=None)

markup_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
btns = ["Order"]
for btn in btns:
    markup_menu.add(types.KeyboardButton(btn))

menu = {"Snacks": {"Sweet Snack": 150, "Salt snak": 320}, "Drinks": {"Cola": 100, "Sprite": 90},
        "Meat": {"Pork": 228, "Beef": 56}}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Wellcome, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>",
                     reply_markup=markup_menu,
                     parse_mode="html")

@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
def order(message):
    # These are variable values to help change next message after "Choose category:"
    order_counter = 0
    product_message = 0
    switcher = {product_message: order_counter}
    if message.text == 'Order':
        order_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        order_menu.row_width = 2
        for category in menu:
            order_menu.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(category,
                                                     callback_data=f"{category}"))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                        "Choose category:",
                        reply_markup=order_menu)
    if order_counter == 0:
        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in menu.keys())
        def callback_product(call):
            product_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            product_menu.row_width = 4
            for product in menu[call.data]:
                product_menu.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton
                                 (f"{product}" +
                                  f" - {menu[call.data][product]}",
                                  callback_data=f"{product}")
                                 )
            product_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                               f'Choose {call.data}:',
                                               reply_markup=product_menu,
                                               )
            product_message
            order_counter == 1
            switcher = {product_message: order_counter}
            return switcher


    elif switcher.keys() == 1:

        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in menu.keys())
        def callback_product1(call):

            product_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            product_menu.row_width = 4
            for product in menu[call.data]:
                product_menu.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton
                                 (f"{product}" +
                                  f" - {menu[call.data][product]}",
                                  callback_data=f"{product}")
                                 )
            product_message = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=switcher[0][0].message.chat.id,
                                                    message_id=switcher[0][0].message_id,
                                                    text=f'Choose {call.data}:',
                                                    reply_markup=product_menu
                                                    )
            product_message
            order_counter == 1
            return order_counter, product_message

    @bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
    def missunderstand(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, "I don't understand you", reply_markup=markup_menu)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

I have tried to create a switcher that would signal to func. if message with subcategories exists, but it didn't work. (it's "switcher" in code)